# SP 2010 SharePoint Designer list item workflow firing more than once

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I created a workflow which is meant to execute whenever a new item is added or existing item is updated in the list. The problem I am facing is it is executing for more than one time.

I am updating a column of the current item in workflow, is it possibly because of Update list item action? 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the workflow to run on creation and update. This is what happens in succession:

1. You create a new item
2. The workflow is fired the first time (Create)
3. The Version is updated (as it would have, had the item been actually modified)
4. The workflow is started again (Modify)

You would have to modify your workflow to avoid that. One way to do it is to get the time between the 'Created' and 'Modified' fields of the item in Designer, and only allow the workflow logic to execute, if the time is more than a specific amount, to ensure that the item is actually being modified by a user and not by the workflow inflicted version increment. 2 workflows: one to run on creation and one to run on modify would make more sense in this scenario, where the aforementioned condition would only be added to the 'Modify' workflow.

Comment: tell us if it worked for you, and please choose my answer as the correct one if it solved your problem.

Comment: I chose the second option, to create different workflows for Created and Changed events instead of merging them together and making it more complex to handle time calculations. Just followed the KISS principle. Although I am not sure if steps suggested by you will work or not. Thank you :)